# Is there a way to share/synchronize contacts between Google accounts?

Tags: synchronization, google-contacts

My wife and I each have our own Google accounts for Gmail, calendar, etc.

Obviously, we know some of the same people. We'd like to keep the contact information for those people shared or at least synchronized between our accounts. But not all of our contacts.

What are our options?

(Sharing calendars is so easy. I wish it was as easy on Google Contacts.)

Comment: Directly: no. With proxies such as a mobile phone or external services such as Plaxo: maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that Google Contacts is one of the services which [does not have a sharing option, but does have a data transfer option](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582).

Transferring data between two Google accounts would involve [exporting](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=24911) and [importing](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77259).

**Update:** One alternative would be to set up a Google Apps account and use one of the workarounds to [share contact information](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/954/what-contact-sharing-options-are-there-in-google-apps).

Comment: Yeah, we did that early on with our "Family" category, but it's too burdensome to do on an ongoing basis.

Comment: @Senseful do you mean to say Transferring data between two Google accounts would involve **manual** exporting and importing?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be our only option for now.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there will be another possibility in the near future:

[Fullcontact](http://www.fullcontact.com/): Though the website states that is only possible to sign up for the beta,
you can create an account under https://app.fullcontact.com/

Answer (score 1):

I use [Soocial](http://www.soocial.com) to keep my contacts synced between Google accounts.  I use Google apps for my email, but also use a Google Voice account.  This is the easiest way I've found so far to keep my contacts in sync.

Addendum: [Soocial.com is shutting down July 31, 2013](http://blog.soocial.com/2013/07/01/we-are-shutting-down-soocial-com/)

Comment: Is it an all-or-nothing affair, or can you determine which contacts get synced?

Comment: You can sort of determine what gets synced.  All your contacts would get synced to soocial, which has it's own contact manager, but then you can sort them into groups and select which ones get pushed back to different connections.  You can also have it only sync contacts that have phone numbers or email address.  

Another note - I think the free version only supports 2 Google accounts.

Comment: They support 3 free accounts but only one Google account, check http://www.soocial.com/pricing

Comment: Unfortunately, [Soocial.com is shutting down on July 31, 2013](http://blog.soocial.com/2013/07/01/we-are-shutting-down-soocial-com/).

Comment: soocial.com url now redirects to viadeo.com that is similar to LinkedIn.

Answer (score -1):

I did not tested this, but setting up an [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) server could be a solution. As stated on their [forums](http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=13154), it supports sharing of contacts.

All contacts from ownCloud could then be synced to Google, I think.