# Shared contacts in Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-contacts

I have some questions regarding the shared contacts in Google Apps. I have posted questions in many forums regarding this but I am not getting any replies. Hence I am not able to troubleshoot the issue. I have enabled the shared contacts option in the control panel of the domain.

How do I create a global address book in Google Apps?

Is it true that after enabling the shared contacts option in the domain settings, the contacts present in anyone of the user's account, will be visible to all the other users present in that same domain?

Answer (score 1):

Shared contact in Google Apps will share only the contacts with emails from the same domain.

So the current implementation makes some sense only for big corporate implementations where it's hard to keep contact with people from inside the company.

From my knowledge, most of the Google Apps clients are small to medium, where you want to share external contact. Bad luck, you have to look for a third party service, like [Is there a way to share/synchronize contacts between Google accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-a-way-to-share-synchronize-contacts-between-google-accounts/1626#1626) - free up to 3 accounts.