# Sharing Gmail contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to share/synchronize contacts between Google accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-a-way-to-share-synchronize-contacts-between-google-accounts)

How do I share my Gmail contact data with other Gmail users, so that they get the updates I make? Can it even be done?

Comment: There is option in gmail contacts --> "Import". To import the contacts as csv file then export it to other gmail account by "Export".

Comment: @Mr_Green: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem of keeping the contacts synchonized. When I update my contact data, my friends do not get the updates.

Comment: I dont know whether it is possible or not. go through this [`Link`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). If this doesnt solve your problem then ask [`here`](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail) for help. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green: That's very interesting, it may actually be possible to code a program that utilizes Google's API to achieve the desired result. However, I won't have the time to do that.