# What's the best way to "share" a Google contact?

Tags: google, google-contacts, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to share/synchronize contacts between Google accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-a-way-to-share-synchronize-contacts-between-google-accounts)

I was wondering if there's any way for us to "share" a contact. Just like in Google Docs, I create a contact (akin to creating a Google Document) and when I share this contact with my friend, my friend can see the contact details of the contact which I've created.

Whenever I update the contact, my friend would always see the latest copy of the contact.

What's the best way to "share" a Google contact?

Comment: An individual contact? You can't, really. There are _some_ options for sharing all (or at least groups of contacts) but most aren't very palatable. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/954/what-contact-sharing-options-are-there-in-google-apps http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-a-way-to-share-synchronize-contacts-between-google-accounts

Comment: @AlEverett: That's not what OP is asking. He wants to share individual contacts with select people not within his domain.

Comment: @dnbrv: Did you see the second question I linked to? It's mine. Because I have a very similar issue as the OP: I want to share a limited number of contact records with my wife's Google account. I only linked the question about Google Apps because perhaps that's an option for the OP.

Comment: @AlEverett so btw was your final solution Soocial  ?

Comment: No, it didn't really work out for me. For those few we need to share we end up doing the export/import thing when they change. I'm hoping GOOG will get around to offering a "real" solution.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open a contact in [GMail Contacts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&shva=1#contacts) or [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com)
2. Click on `More...`
3. Click on `Export...`
4. In the dialogue window, make sure that `Selected contacts (1)` under **Which contacts do you want to export?** and `Google CSV` under **Which export format?** are selected.
5. Click the blue `Export` button
6. Save the file on your computer
7. Start composing a new email to the friend with whom you wish to share the contact & add the saved file as an attachment

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, since the originator would need to re-export every time a change was made to the Contact.

Comment: Do your contacts change their information every week? Or every month?

Comment: @dnbrv with each contact information changing once a year, having 365 contacts means having to change on average once a day.

Comment: And do you share all 365 contacts all the time? You're creating a non-existent consumer edge case that can be solved with enterprise offerings.